# Interfacing With IEC 62056 - 21 port via RS232

Tags: rs232

I need to read energy meters (electricity prepaid meters or smart meters)  information via the optical port in DLMS or IEC 62056-21 using RS232 interface. I already have the optical port and a ready energy meter to read but I dont know the command tos send via the RS232 to do this. Anyone knows how to do this?